# to the back of the bus

Tags: meaning

What does "**to the back of the bu**s" mean in

> All of these options push the important element of demand **to the back of the bus**. And, those in the demand part of the equation—aka consumers—are faced with a dizzying array of options come meal time.

Note this is from *The Spoon*'s "[Former Uber CEO Lands in the Cloud Kitchen Market](https://thespoon.tech/former-uber-ceo-lands-in-the-cloud-kitchen-market/)" (link to article, which dishes up the context).

Comment: Hello OSB and welcome to the site. I have edited your question to add a link to the article containing the quote; this is to provide proper attribution and to provide context for the part you quoted. However, I am not sure this question will remain open, as we generally require your thoughts on the matter in terms of (a) research you have done and/or (b) your pointing out exactly what in the phrase does not make sense to you. When you include this information, it helps us address what exactly you don't understand, and at the same time prevents us from duplicating your own research efforts.

Comment: @user070221 I think the usage, and therefore the meaning, of the two terms are different, so not a duplicate.

Comment: @KillingTime - possibly the one OP is asking us derived from the other.

Comment: @KillingTime - I interpret the OP's quote as suggesting "unfair treatment", as stated in the suggested dupe.  It's a bit unclear, though -- a poor use of metaphor.